# Why ArcGIS Topology "Must Not Have Dangle" can be fixed with Planarize tool (Advance Editing) even its still have dangle?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I have some project fixing line features that "must have no dangle" but when I use planarize tool on error part, the error was fixed. can anyone explain this?

Comment: Can you add screen shot of what you are viewing?

Comment: Problem Fixed, its need a revalidate and the feature will detected as error again, I want to add picture here but I don't know how

Comment: Click on edit above for your question. If you have figured out the answer then I would suggest you post the answer below to your questions and mark answered, so that others may benefit from your Q/A.